# Iphone Tabbar application not rotating

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I created a tabbar application. First there were rotation enabled. The app did rotate without any difficulties. But for better usage i commented all auto rotation code and also in the infoplist deleted all other interface except portrait. But now i need it back. I uncommented all code and also added all interface orientation. But the application is not rotating. Please any one help me.Sorry for my bad english

Thanks 
Rakesh

Comment: If any of viewControllers of tabBarController does not permit rotation, all others will not be rotated too. Something like this.

Comment: what code should i give?

Comment: thanks Roman Temchecnko the answer was right. The problem was i didnt gave it to every view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every view controller added to tab bar controller will have

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

Make sure you return YES in each of them..

Comment: sorry guys i got it Shubhank thanks you helped i didnt gave it to all view controllers now its solved

Answer (score 0):

```
create a category like this and this method
   @implementation UITabBarController(UITabBarControllerCategory)

 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
  (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication     sharedApplication]delegate];

   if ([AppDelegate isLandScapeOnly]){



      return NO;
 }
    return YES;
 }

 @end
```